# Perdendo qualidade da imagem ao redimensionar no pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Eu tenho algumas imagens de cartas no tamanho 140x190 e estou usando o metodo `pygame.trnasform.scale` para redimensionar para 105x143 que é um valor proporcional. Porém está perdendo a qualidade, enquanto que as imagens dos versos que são basciamente uma cor de fundo e uma borda branca não perdem. Como resolver isso?

Codigo dentro da classe:

```
    self.frente = pygame.image.load("imagens/{}/carta ({}).png".format(naipe, valor)).convert()
    self.frente = pygame.transform.scale(self.frente, [98, 133])
    self.verso = pygame.image.load("imagens/versos/azul (1).png")
    self.verso = pygame.transform.scale(self.verso, [98, 133])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar essa perda de qualidade, você pode usar o método [`pygame.transform.smoothscale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale) para redimensionar a imagem com um filtro especial de *smooth*.

No exemplo abaixo foi utilizado uma [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqIPG.png) no formato `PNG` com transparência, onde ela foi redimensionada e exibida em 7 escalas diferentes `1.0`,`0.88`,`0.75`,`0.5`,`0.33`,`0.25` e `0.1`:

```
import pygame

running = True
verde_escuro = (0,128,0)

# Inicializa pygame
pygame.init();

# Inicializa janela com fundo verde escuro
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1350, 480))
screen.fill(verde_escuro)

# Carrega uma imagem PNG com transparencia
img = pygame.image.load("carta.png").convert_alpha()

# Recupera as dimensoes da imagem
w, h = img.get_size()

# Escalas da imagem
scales = [ 1, 0.88, 0.75, 0.5, 0.33, 0.25, 0.1 ]

# Exibe a mesma imagem, em escalas diferentes, lado a lado.
posx = 0
for s in scales:
    redim = pygame.transform.smoothscale( img, (int(w*s), int(h*s)) )
    screen.blit( redim, (posx, 0) )
    posx += int(w*s)

# Loop principal de eventos
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    clock.tick(10)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.flip()

# Fim
pygame.exit()
sys.exit()
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]